# Cocoa Bindings to new NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I am new to this, so I will lay out what I am doing and please correct any mistakes.

In my AppDelegate, I have a @property for an NSManagedObject subclass, "Entry". When I press a button on the main window to create a new Entry, I first instantiate the property:

```
_entry = (Entry*)[NSEntityDescription
                    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entry"
                    inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

then I open up a new window by calling

```
[inputWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

This inputWindow has Cocoa Bindings to the entry's properties. When I submit, I do the usual save

```
[[self managedObjectContext] save:&error];
```

and then

```
[inputWindow performClose:nil];
```

This seems pretty straight forward, but I get an error:

```
2014-01-11 22:57:32.906 WriteOffs[66441:303] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Entry' 
2014-01-11 22:57:32.943 WriteOffs[66441:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-01-11 22:57:32.943 WriteOffs[66441:303] [<Entry 0x6100000ba040> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "date".
```

It seems that entry is null, implying that the inputWindow and its bindings are instantiated before I click the button on the main window to create the new entry and open up the inputWindow.

Seems like there is a simple solution that I am missing.

EDIT:

Here's what I have. In WOAppDelegate.h,

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "Entry.h"

@interface WOAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *inputWindow;

@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) Entry *entry;


@end
```

Then in WOAppDelegate.m

```
#import "WOAppDelegate.h"

@implementation WOAppDelegate

@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;

@synthesize inputWindow = _inputWindow;
@synthesize entry = _entry;

// Core Data Stuff...
```

Entry.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Entry : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * amount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * category;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * payee;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * text;

@end
```

Entry.m

```
#import "Entry.h"

@implementation Entry

@dynamic amount;
@dynamic category;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic images;
@dynamic payee;
@dynamic text;

@end
```

Pretty simple. In my MainMenu.xib, I have the main window, and the inputWindow. I have an array controller binded to the managedObjectContext that fills in content for the table on the main window. I also have a second window for entering in new entries to the table. This is bonded to the property, entry.

Thanks again for the help,

Chet

Answer (score 0):

Does your “Entry” class maybe override some of the methods in NSManagedObject? Maybe even

```
- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

If so, do you fail to call -super in any of your subclass’s methods?

Comment: I didn't write any methods in Entry.m. I've commented out almost all my code. All I have is an /@property and associated /@synthesize in the AppDelegate and I get this error still. I think what happens is the entry window is being loaded (right away) before the binded object is instantiated. I tried instantiating entity in awakeFromNib, but that didn't work. I'm really unsure what I'm doing here. Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try logging self.managedObjectContext to make sure it’s not nil? Can you post what remains of your Entry.h and Entry.m (delete the commented-out parts) so we can see the code?

Comment: not sure where to log self.managedObjectContext. I put it in applicationDidFinishLaunching and the program crashed before getting to it. Also see my edit for more code and explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the array controller, I had mode:Class referencing the Entry class. I changed that to mode:Entity referencing the Entry entity and everything worked out. :)

Can someone comment on why the debugger is so bad at giving a meaningful response? Where in the error message could have pointed me to this being the error?

```
2014-01-12 18:35:31.520 WriteOffs[68395:303] CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Entry' 
2014-01-12 18:35:31.555 WriteOffs[68395:303] An uncaught exception was raised
2014-01-12 18:35:31.555 WriteOffs[68395:303] [<Entry 0x6100000a9a20> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "date".
2014-01-12 18:35:31.556 WriteOffs[68395:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b93f41c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff944f3e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b93efc9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   CoreData                            0x00007fff89650b14 -[NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey:] + 276
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff91eff49f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 334
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff89c872d3 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:atIndex:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 408
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff89963567 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 622
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a022008 -[NSValueBinder updateTableColumnDataCell:forDisplayAtIndex:] + 143
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff89f9e2ee -[NSTextValueBinder updateTableColumnDataCell:forDisplayAtIndex:] + 73
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b873639 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 137
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b872ddf -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 319
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a062ac7 -[_NSBindingAdaptor tableColumn:willDisplayCell:row:] + 108
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff89b8ada0 -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 615
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff89b8a9ee -[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 44
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff89b8a723 -[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] + 1629
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff89b89f7d -[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 776
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a534c2 -[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1484
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2c399 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3748
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2ac0e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1799
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2afea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2afea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2afea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2afea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a28a50 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 841
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a28201 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 314
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a25209 -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2828
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a0463a -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1680
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a1e246 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1972
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a1d7f0 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 786
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a1d470 -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] + 162
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fff898bbc26 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1406
    31  AppKit                              0x00007fff898b05fe loadNib + 327
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff898afb9c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 288
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff898af98c -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 197
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff898af77b +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 357
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff898ab617 NSApplicationMain + 448
    36  WriteOffs                           0x0000000100002e02 main + 34
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8eddf5fd start + 1
    38  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
2014-01-12 18:35:31.640 WriteOffs[68395:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Entry 0x6100000a9a20> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity (null) is not key value coding-compliant for the key "date".'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b93f41c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff944f3e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b93efc9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   CoreData                            0x00007fff89650b14 -[NSManagedObject valueForUndefinedKey:] + 276
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff91eff49f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 334
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff89c872d3 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:atIndex:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 408
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff89963567 -[NSValueBinder _adjustObject:mode:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:editableState:adjustState:] + 622
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff8a022008 -[NSValueBinder updateTableColumnDataCell:forDisplayAtIndex:] + 143
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff89f9e2ee -[NSTextValueBinder updateTableColumnDataCell:forDisplayAtIndex:] + 73
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b873639 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 137
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b872ddf -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 319
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8a062ac7 -[_NSBindingAdaptor tableColumn:willDisplayCell:row:] + 108
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff89b8ada0 -[NSTableView preparedCellAtColumn:row:] + 615
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff89b8a9ee -[NSTableView _drawContentsAtRow:column:withCellFrame:] + 44
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff89b8a723 -[NSTableView drawRow:clipRect:] + 1629
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff89b89f7d -[NSTableView drawRowIndexes:clipRect:] + 776
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a534c2 -[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1484
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2c399 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 3748
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2ac0e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1799
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2afea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    20  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2afea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    21  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2afea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    22  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a2afea -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2787
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a28a50 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 841
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a28201 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 314
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a25209 -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2828
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a0463a -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1680
    27  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a1e246 -[NSWindow _reallyDoOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 1972
    28  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a1d7f0 -[NSWindow _doOrderWindow:relativeTo:findKey:forCounter:force:isModal:] + 786
    29  AppKit                              0x00007fff89a1d470 -[NSWindow orderWindow:relativeTo:] + 162
    30  AppKit                              0x00007fff898bbc26 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1406
    31  AppKit                              0x00007fff898b05fe loadNib + 327
    32  AppKit                              0x00007fff898afb9c +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 288
    33  AppKit                              0x00007fff898af98c -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 197
    34  AppKit                              0x00007fff898af77b +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 357
    35  AppKit                              0x00007fff898ab617 NSApplicationMain + 448
    36  WriteOffs                           0x0000000100002e02 main + 34
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8eddf5fd start + 1
    38  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```